# Prove sum of finite sequence of bounded real valued functions is also bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, metric-spaces

I'm having trouble proving the below:
Let $f^1$... $f^N$ be a finite sequence of bounded functions in a metric space (X, $d_x$) to R. Prove that the $\sum_{i=1}^N f^i$ is also bounded.

The problem I'm having is proving this using the ball definition of bounded functions. My first guess was to use induction:

Base Case: $f^1$ is bounded

Step Case: Assume ${h^{N-1}}$ = $f^1$+...+$f^{N-1}$ is bounded

Induction Step:
Suffices to prove that sum of ${h^{N-1}}$ and $f^N$ are bounded.

Because $f^N$ is bounded, there $\exists$  B($y_0$,$r_1$) such that    $f^N$(x) $\in$ B($y_0$,$r_1$), $\forall$ x $\in$ X.

Similarly there $\exists$ B($y_0$,$r_2$)  such that  ${h^{N-1}}$(x) $\in$ B($y_0$,$r_2$), $\forall$ x $\in$ X.

Let r = max{$r_1$,$r_2$} then:
$f^N$(x), ${h^{N-1}}$(x) both lie in B($y_0$,$r$) for $\forall$ x $\in$ X.

As r > max{$d$($y_0$, $f^N$(x)) and $d$($y_0$, ${h^{N-1}}$(x)),  $\forall$ x $\in$ X} the sum:

$f^N$(x) + ${h^{N-1}}$(x) $\in$  B($y_0$,$2r$), $\forall$ x $\in$ X so $\sum_{i=1}^N f^i$ is bounded.

Does this seem correct?

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to handle the problem. I appreciate that your Q is about your work. I have not examined your work yet.

Definition: A subset $A$ of a metric space  $Y$ with metric $e$ is a bounded subset iff $\sup \{e(x,y):x,y\in A\}<\infty.$

[I].  Equivalently, for $Y\ne \phi,$ there exists $z\in S$ and $r> 0$  such that $A\subset B_e(z,r).$  Proof: (i). The case $A=\phi$ is trivial.

(ii). If $A \ne  \phi$ is bounded, take any $z\in A$ and let $r=1+\sup \{e(z,a):a\in A\}.$ We have $r\leq 1+\sup \{e(a',a):a',a\in A\}<\infty.$  And for all  $a\in A$ we have $a\in B_e(z,r).$

(iii). If $z\in S$ and $r>0$ and  $A\subset B_e(z,r)$ then $\sup \{ e(x,y):x,y\in A\} \leq \sup \{e(x,z)+e(z,y):x,y\in A\}\leq 2r<\infty.$

[II]. Notatation: For a function $f$ and a set $C\subset$ dom $(f),$ set theorists employ the notation $f''C=\{f(x):x\in C\}.$

Definition: For metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(Y,e),$ a function $f:X\to Y$ is bounded iff $f''X$ is a bounded subset of $Y.$

[III]. Now let $Y=\Bbb R$ and $e(y,y')=|y-y'|.$ Then by [I], any  $A\subset Y$  is bounded iff $A\subset B_e(z,r)=(-r+x,r+z)$ for some $z\in \Bbb R$ and some $r> 0.$

So if $f_i:X\to \Bbb R$ is bounded for $1\leq i\leq n,$ then let $f_i''X\subset (-r_i+z_1,r_i+z_i)$ for $1\leq i\leq n,$ with $r_i> 0$ and $z_i\in \Bbb R.$

Let $D=\sum_{i=1}^n (-r_i+z_i)$ and $U=\sum_{i=1}^n (r_i+z_i).$ Let $g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)$ for $x\in X.$

For each $i,$ and each $x\in X,$ we have $-r_i+z_i<f_i(x)<r_i+z_i .$ So  $D<g(x)<U.$  Hence $$g''X\subset (D,U)=B_e( (U+D)/2, (U-D)/2).$$ So by [I}, $g$ is a bounded function.

Remark: Many writers use $f(C)$  for $f''C.$ Set-theorists object on the grounds that  $C$ could be  both a subset of dom $(f)$ and a member of dom $(f).$ However, in many topics we  often can ( & usually implicitly do) assume (WLOG) that almost  any object or structure $T$ under discussion is anti-transitive, i.e. that members of $T$ are not subsets of $T.$